# Posh-Git throwing ssh error while trying to pull from origin

Tags: git, github, posh-git

I'm unable to pull from origin when using posh-git module. Is there a way to configure my existing ssh keys location with posh-git to use them? The native git works fine.

Error Details:

```
C:\Git\MyRepo [master ≡]
> git pull origin master

    Could not create directory '/h//.ssh'.
    The authenticity of host 'domain.net (10.a.b.xyz)' can't be established.
    ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nxxxx.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
    Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/h/.ssh/known_hosts).
    git@domain.net: Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "native git" ?

Comment: I mean it works without using/importing the posh-git module. I see this problem when I try to use posh-git module. ref: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

Comment: Somehow, ssh looks for its config files in `/h/` instead of `$HOME`. Try running `ssh domain.net` to see if you have the same error.

Comment: Ok : it works from Powershell when not loading `posh-git`, right ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Look at your environment before and after loading posh-git (I don't remember by heart how to do it from Powershell)

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I think I have found the problem. I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to check my home path using powershell,

```
Command: $env:HOME
Output:  H:\
```

But I didn't have any H:\ drive in my computer, so I updated it to my home directory where my .ssh folder is located.

```
Command: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HOME", "C:\Users\<UserName>", "User")
```

It worked after I have completely closed and re-opened powershell :)

Comment: glad I could help. Was there a link between "activating posh-git in your shell" and "having your $HOME env variable messed up" ? If yes, it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @LeGEC I’m not 100% sure on that part. Whether posh-git did that or some other bugged application in my computer did that.